# AbstractUser Django full example

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-users, django-1.5

I am new to Django and I have been trying this for weeks, but could not find a way to solve this problem.

I want to store additional information like user mobile number, bank name, bank account. And want to store the mobile number while user registers and wants user to login with either (mobile number and password) or (email and password).

This is my UserProfile model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

     user_mobile = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True)
     user_bank_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
     user_bank_account_number=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
     user_bank_ifsc_code = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
     user_byt_balance = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, null=True)
```

And this is my forms.py

```
from django import forms            
from django.contrib.auth.models import User   # fill in custom user info then save it 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm      
from models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    mobile = forms.IntegerField(required=True)



    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2','mobile' )        

    def save(self,commit = False):   
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.user_mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile']
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])

        user_default = User.objects.create_user(self.cleaned_data['username'],
                                                self.cleaned_data['email'],
                                                self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user_default.save()

        if commit:
             user.save()

         return user
```

In my settings.py I have included

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "registration.UserProfile"
```

admin.py of my app is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from models import UserProfile

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'userprofile'

 class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )

 admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

While adding the user from admin I get this error

```
Exception at /admin/registration/userprofile/1/
<class 'registration.models.UserProfile'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'registration.models.UserProfile'>
```

Can someone help me with this or point out to the full working exapmle, I have seen Django documentation but didn't find any luck. Or if there is another way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Edit 1:

While registering from the registration form I'm also getting this error

```
DatabaseError at /register
(1146, "Table 'django_auth_db.auth_user' doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 6):

You have confused yourself a bit here. The idea of subclassing AbstractUser - and defining `AUTH_USER_MODEL` as your subclass - is that the new model completely replaces auth.models.User. You shouldn't be importing the original User at all, and you certainly should be calling `User.objects.create_user()`: your new model's manager now has its own create_user method.

Because of this, there's no reason to muck about with inline admins. Your UserProfile should be registered in the admin using the existing django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin class.

Comment: Can you provide a link where i can see full implementation of Django AbstractUser with registration form and views.  

I'm struck here from 2 weeks could not find a way out.

Answer (score 2):

Inlines forms assume that you have a Generic ForeignKey on your model, in this case, the UserProfileAdmin expect a Generic ForeignKey of the UserProfile, that does not exists. Try to do a regular Model Admin, like:

```python
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'userprofile'

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```